# Circle Pack Layout D3 - remove add nodes on new data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a situation where I want users to browse 3 different data sets using circle pack layout. I am using [Bostock's Zoomable circle packing](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535).

I have added 3 options additionally which loads data and creates new nodes. Here chartid is passed from these elements.

function changeDataSet(chartid)
{
    console.log(chartid);
    //console.log(nodes);

```
//add new chart data depending on the selected option
if(chartid === "plevels")
{
  root = JSON.parse(newKmap_slevels);
  focus = root;
  nodes = pack.nodes(root);
}
else if (chartid === "pduration")
{
  root = JSON.parse(newKmap_sduration);
  focus = root;
  nodes = pack.nodes(root);
}
else
{
  root = JSON.parse(newKmap_stype);
  focus = root;
  nodes = pack.nodes(root);
}

refresh();
```

}

Then I have the refresh function, but I am not understnading how to remove existting nodes, and add new ones based on the new data set. Showing some transition animations would be nice also.

Currently I am trying to remove and recreate the initial elements, but the chart goes blank when I do that.

```
  var refresh = function() {
  //var nodes = pack.nodes(root);
  var duration = 10;
  console.log(nodes);
  d3.select("#conf_knowledge_map").selectAll("g")
    .remove();

  svg
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

  circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
      .on("click", function(d) {
        if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation();
      });

  text = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
      .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
      .text(function(d) {
        //console.log(d);
        if( d.size )
        {
            return d.name + ":" + d.size;
        }
        else
          return d.name;
      });
}
```

So my question is how can I remove and then create new nodes on click?

**UPDATE**

I was able to remove all nodes and add the new nodes based on the new data, but now on click to zoom the layout is all messed up. The transform function is not applied to the new nodes somehow.

```
    var refresh = function() {
  svg.selectAll(".node").remove();
  svg.selectAll(".label").remove();

  var nodes = pack.nodes(root);
  focus = root;
  circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
      .attr("r", function(d) {  return d.r;})
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
         console.log(d);
        // if(d.depth === 0)
        //   return 0;
        // else
          // return d.x - (diameter/2);
          return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return d.y;
      })
      // .attr("transform", "translate(" + "x" + "," + "y" + ")")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
      .on("click", function(d) {
        // d.x = d.x - (diameter/2);
        // d.y = d.y - (diameter/2);
        if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation();
      });

  text = svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("x", function(d) {return d.x - (diameter/2);})
      .attr("y", function(d) {return d.y - (diameter/2);})
      .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
      .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
      // .attr("transform", "translate(" + "x" + "," + "y" + ")")
      .text(function(d) {
        //console.log(d);
        if( d.size )
        {
            return d.name + ":" + d.size;
        }
        else
          return d.name;
      });

}
```

How can I transform the new nodes to be in place and for the zoom to work properly?

**UPDATE 2**
Now the transform is working properly after attaching 'g' element to the circles, and showing all the nodes and text correctly. The only problem now is that the zoom does not work when I click on the circles!!

```
      circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
      .attr("r", function(d) {  return d.r;})
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        if(d.depth === 0)
          return 0;
        else
          return d.x - (diameter/2);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        if(d.depth === 0)
          return 0;
        else
          return d.y - (diameter/2);
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null;})
      .on("click", function(d) {
        if (focus !== d) zoom(d); d3.event.stopPropagation();
      })
      .append("g")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
      ;
```

How to make the zoom work??

Comment: can you add your code or fiddle so that we can test ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It so happens that I was making the mistake of simultaneously creating three independent circle pack layouts, with mixed statements one after the other. This was problematic as when you have to select svg sections, different elements were all getting selected and wrongly attached with different events.

So I decided to separate the three implementations and create the three layouts one after the other, only after each one finished. This way I kept the section selection and attaching events etc, separate and then load them as and when required.